# Посимвольный консольный ввод через Stream Java 8

Tags: java, input, консоль, java-stream

Как можно преобразовать консольный ввод System.in в Stream из символов.

Пробовал такую комбинацию:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).lines()
```

Но проблема что он выдают всю строку, а не поток символов, например я не могу ее обрезать с помощью limit().
Для уточнения скажу что хочу брать из консоли число и превращать его в массив int. Пробовал такой способ, но он так-же берёт числа одним куском и в добавок обрезает нули в начале если они были.

```
IntStream.of(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()).limit(4).forEach(System.out::println)
```

Хотелось бы вытягивать из ввода числа посимвольно с помошью стрима и потом где-то на промежуточном этапе превращать в int и под конец складывать в массив.

Спасибо всем за ответы, решил следующим образом:

```
int[] inArr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
                .readLine()
                .chars()
                .filter(Character::isDigit)
                .map(Character::getNumericValue)
                .limit(3)
                .toArray();
```

Comment: А что мешает сразу прочитать строку и разбить ее уже потом на символы?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov на сколько я понял автора, ему нужно запрашивать ввод до тех пор, пока не будут введены четыре **цифры**, после чего преобразовать их в массив соответствующих чисел.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev можно как вариант тогда заюзать реактивное программирование

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
String str = "hello world";
str
   .chars()
   .mapToObj(e -> (char) e)
   .limit(3)
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод:

> h
>   e
>   l

Comment: Автор вопроса, ведь этот код не делает то, что описано у вас в вопросе. Это вопрос неправильно сформулирован или ответ неправильно выбран?

Comment: @Hivemaster почему вы решили что он не то делает? Вместо фиксированной строки можно подставить считывание из файла или консоли, и будет то что нужно

Comment: А вы вчитайтесь внимательно в текст вопроса. Автору нужно, чтобы например цифра 0 введённая в консоли преобразовалась в элемент массива со значением 0. Да и в апдейте у него код куда более похожий на непринятый ответ.

Comment: Не обижайтесь, ничего личного. У вас хорошие ответы. Просто я не могу понять логику автора вопроса.

Answer (score 5):

В девятке этот вопрос решается элементарно:

```
int[] ints = new Scanner(System.in)
               .tokens()
               .flatMapToInt(String::chars)
               .filter(Character::isDigit)
               .map(Character::getNumericValue)
               .limit(4)
               .toArray();
```

В восьмёрке придётся немного извернуться:

```
public class Example {
    public static Stream<String> scannerStream(Scanner scanner) {
        Spliterator<String> spliterator
          = Spliterators.spliterator(scanner,
                                     Long.MAX_VALUE,
                                     Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL);
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false)
                            .onClose(scanner::close);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] ints = scannerStream(scanner)
                       .flatMapToInt(String::chars)
                       .filter(Character::isDigit)
                       .map(Character::getNumericValue)
                       .limit(4)
                       .toArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
    }
}
```